Sort posts based on an acf field called fecha value return longtext '20240517'
I have a field called acf date for certain posts and I need to sort these posts by this field, but the value comes in this format: '20240517' and I need to sort the posts in ascending order with this field but my template has by default some queries a little bit confusing for my level
here is my code:
do_action( 'bp_before_activity_loop' ); ?>

<?php 
$args_post = array (
    'post_tipe' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tipo-de-contenido',
            'terms' => "actividades-y-talleres  ",
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
);
$meta_query = array();
if(isset($_COOKIE["region_filter"])){
    $region_filter = $_COOKIE["region_filter"];
    $sevice_range = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'lugar',
            'value'   => $region_filter,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'region',
            'value'   => $region_filter,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    );
    array_push($meta_query, $sevice_range);
}
$args_post['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
$posts = new WP_Query( $args_post);
if(count($posts->posts)){
    $args2 = array( 
        'secondary_id' => $posts->posts,
        'action' => ['activity_update', 'new_blog_post'],
        'per_page' => 8
    );
}else{
    $args2 = array( 
        'secondary_id' => array(-1),
        'action' => ['activity_update', 'new_blog_post'],
        'per_page' => 8
    );
}
if(!empty($args)){
    if(!empty($args['page'])){
        $args2['page'] = $args['page'];
    }
}


Juste a note: I would not recommend using $_COOKIE in your code because all WordPress sites should use caching and if you are using caching you won't be able to access those cookies properly. Unless you bypass cache when the cookie is present, but if you want a fast site, it's not recommended. If anything you should be using URL params and checking with $_GET or passing the filter data via AJAX.

You should be able to order your posts by adding the following to your main args:
'meta_key' => 'date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',

Example:
$args_post = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tipo-de-contenido',
            'terms' => 'actividades-y-talleres',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
);

You mentioned in your question that the field is named "acf date", in my code I'm assuming the field name is actually just "date" as the former wouldn't make much sense. If that's not the case be sure to change 'date' to your actual field name.
